# Why is django throwing a system error?

Tags: django, django-admin

I am building a custom user that uses an email as a username.
When I run the server to create a custom admin, I get this error

```
class 'user.admin.UserAdmin'>: (admin.E116) The value of
'list_filter[0]' refers to 'is_staff', which does not refer to a
Field.
```

**Here is my code for the admin.py**

```
    from django import forms
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
    from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin 
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField

    from .models import BaseUser

class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password.
    """
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label='Password',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label='Password confirmation',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput
    )

    class Meta:
        model = BaseUser
        fields = ('email',) 

    def clean_password2(self):
        #Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

        if password1 and password2 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Password do not match')
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
        """
        A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
        the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
        password hash display field.
        """

        password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

        class Meta:
            model = BaseUser
            fields = (
                'email',
                'password',
                'user_first_name',
                'user_last_name',
                'user_mobile',
                'is_a_student',
            )

        def clean_password(self):
            return self.initial["password"]

class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
#Forms to add and change user instances
        form = UserChangeForm
        add_form = UserCreationForm

        #The fields to be used in displaying User model.
        #These overried the definitions on the base UserAdmin
        #That reference specific fields on auth.User


        list_display = (
            'email',
        )
        list_filter = ('is_staff',)

        fieldsets = (
            (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
            ('Personal info', {'fields': (
                'user_first_name',
                'user_last_name',
                'user_mobile',
            )}),
            ('Permission', {'fields': (
                'is_a_student',
            )})
        )

        # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
        # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
        add_fieldsets = (
            (None, {
                'classes': ('wide',),
                'fields': (
                    'email',
                    'password1',
                    'password2',
                    'user_first_name',
                    'user_last_name',
                    'user_mobile',
                    'is_a_student',
                )}
             ),
        )


        search_fields = ('email',)
        ordering = ('email',)
        filter_horizontal = ()

#Register the new UserAdmin        
admin.site.register(BaseUser, UserAdmin)
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

**Here is the models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.utils.http import urlquote
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
)


class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email and password
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email=email,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_superuser = user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class BaseUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )

    user_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    user_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mobile_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1\d{9,15}$', message="Please enter a max of 10 digits :)")
    user_mobile = models.CharField(validators=[mobile_regex], blank=True, max_length=10)
    is_a_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'User'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users'

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        """
        Does the user have a specific permission?
        """
        return True

    def is_student(self):
        return self.is_a_student

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        """
        Is the user a member of staff?
        """
        return self.is_staff

    def emai_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None):
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email])
```

**Options done**

 - I already took out all of the is_staff attribute in admin.py and still got an  error.

 - Refactored it many times to check if the problem is in different areas of my code.

At this point I am stuck. Could someone please help debug this?

Answer (score 4):

```
#list_filter = ('is_staff',)
list_filter = ('is_admin',)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add this line which will filter your data in django-admin I had the same issue I resloved it by doing this in my admin.py file or for more brief information you can check out this wonderful tutorial:
[Custom Django User Admin](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/how-to-create-a-custom-django-user-model/)

```
`list_filter = ('admin', 'staff', or anything which you want to add in filter list)`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        """
        Is the user a member of staff?
        """
        return self.is_staff
```

The above code creates a recursive execution which caused the error.

```
    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        """
        Is the user a member of staff?
        """
        return self.is_staff
```

Answer (score 0):

As Django "talks" about field i would check the model in a first review 
i couldn't find any password or password1 nor password2 field in the model for example.